# Get list of values inside a multi-dimensional php array

Tags: php

I need to change this array:

```
$array = [
        [0] => [
            'id' => '100'
        ],
        [1] => [
            'id' => '200'
        ],
        [2] => [
            'id' => '300'
        ]
    ];
```

Into this:
`$array2 = [100, 200, 300]`;

A long time ago I found a built-in PHP function which could do this for me. But i can't for the life of me remember which one it was. Of course I could do it manually, but it would be easier and more readable if I could use a builtin PHP function

Comment: $result=array(); foreach ($array as $el){ array_push($result, $el["id"]};

Comment: **WARNING** Illegal offset type on line number ...

Answer (score 1):

Use [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) like this: `array_column($array, 'id');`

Comment: this is the simplest, but note you must be running PHP 5 >= 5.5.0 or PHP 7

Answer (score 0):

**1st solution:**

Use [**`array_map()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) function with inline function:

```
$array2 = array_map(function($arrayElement){return $arrayElement['id'];}, $array);
```

**2nd solution:**

Use `foreach` loop:

```
function getValues($array, $index)
{
    $result = array();
    foreach($array as $element)
    {
        if(isset($element[$index])) //check if index exists
            $result[] = $element[$index];
    }

    return $result;
}

$array2 = getValues($array, 'id');
```

This function has two parameters: array from which you gets values and index, for example `'id'`.

Result of two methods is the same:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 100
    [1] => 200
    [2] => 300
)
```